Call Javascript function from WasmJsMain
I have created the default example app from KM Wizard with Web target. Then I have compiled it using Gradle task and it works.
.\gradlew :composeApp:wasmJsBrowserDevelopmentRun

However, I would like to a simple Javascript function:
Example App\composeApp\src\wasmJsMain\resources\my_library.js
function greet(name) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
}

I also imported it in index.html next to the file.
Example App\composeApp\src\wasmJsMain\resources\index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example App</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="my_library.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

I modified the common Compose App so that it accepts a string instead of hard-coded data.
Example App\composeApp\src\commonMain\kotlin\com\example\example\App.kt
@Composable
@Preview
fun App(title: String = "default") { // Add parameter
    MaterialTheme {
        var showContent by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Button(onClick = { showContent = !showContent }) {
                Text(title) // Use parameter
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(showContent) {
                val greeting = remember { Greeting().greet() }
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Image(painterResource(Res.drawable.compose_multiplatform), null)
                    Text("Compose: $greeting")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And then I attempted to call the Javascript function from WasmJsMain and pass the result to the Compose App.
Example App\composeApp\src\wasmJsMain\kotlin\com\example\example\main.kt
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun main() {
    ComposeViewport(document.body!!) {
        App(title = greet("world"))
    }
}

// This should pair with the Javascript function
external fun greet(name: String): String

Apparently the Javascript was not found during the build because Gradlew outputs an error:
:composeApp:wasmJsBrowserDevelopmentRun > <i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'kotlin, ..\..\..\..\composeApp\b...

How can I fix this and make the call from Kotlin to Javascript successfully?

In KMP, wasmJsMain should automatically be able to import classes, objects, and interfaces from commonMain. Typically, your wasmJsMain file will include an import statement like so:
import com.example.example.YourClassNameHere.greet

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun main() {
    ComposeViewport(document.body!!) {
        App(title = greet("world"))
    }
}

I noticed you put your function in the "build" directory.  That's not the right place if you're sharing code.  You'll want to put it in commonMain/src/Kotlin/com/example/example/my_library.kt

You don't understand, my_library is Javascript file NOT Kotlin. I put it in wasmJsMain/resources and imported it in the index.html file next to it. Still the same error.

I'm still conducting research, but in the meantime, I wanted to provide some background info on the folder structures:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-discover-project.html
